# What is the best way to draw a color shifting sequence of Divs?

Tags: html, colors

I have a grid of divs that need to gradually animate from one color to another.  I'm concerned that setting the colors via `style.backgroundColor` will be really really slow because of the endless conversion of the hex color value to the three RGB hex integers that are then modified and have to be converted back to integer.

Has anyone done this successfully? and if this isn't the right approach, what would be? Does it make sense to implement a canvas here, and if so, will that work as a background element to other elements that sit on top of it?

Answer (score 0):

Just some food for thought, but you could avoid animations by simply fading in and out the backgrounds that you want.

edit: here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hKBZ9/1/